# want to keep the app in the foreground while executing feature files using CucumberAndroidJUnitRunner

Tags: bdd, android-testing, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I want to keep the app in the foreground while executing feature files using CucumberAndroidJUnitRunner , Right now after executing below command from application,  app is going background , but i want app to be in foreground and show result of each test scenario .

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

command is below ..

/system/bin/am instrument -w -e debug false -e class com.sample.auto.androidBDD.MyAppCucumberAndroidJUnitRunner   -e features /features/Release/ExecuteCommand_method.feature com.sample.auto.androidBDD.test/com.sample.auto.androidBDD.MyAppCucumberAndroidJUnitRunner

I can see feature file execution happening properly from logs and i can see results generated in html format once after execution. I want to see results in the android app screen while executing the feature file .

sample below ..

1. Asset folder we have .feature file
2. Step Implementation class is a feature file implementation
3. TestRunner class update in gradle file
   testInstrumentationRunner "com.sample.auto.androidBDD.TestRunner (MyAppCucumberAndroidJUnitRunner)"
4. @CucumberOptions(
   //features = {"features/bodyaccess/login.feature"},
   glue = "com.sample.auto.androidBDD",
   plugin = { "pretty" "json:/data/user/10/com.sample.auto.androidBDD/cache/cucumber-reports/report.json"},
   monochrome = true
   )
   public class MyAppCucumberAndroidJUnitRunner extends CucumberAndroidJUnitRunner {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
   super.onCreate(arguments);
   }
   }
5. From Terminal :: adb shell am instrument -w -e debug false -e class com.sample.auto.androidBDD.MyAppCucumberAndroidJUnitRunner -e features /features/Release/ExecuteCommand_method.feature com.sample.auto.androidBDD.test/com.sample.auto.androidBDD.MyAppCucumberAndroidJUnitRunner
6. From code :: Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

command is below ..

/system/bin/am instrument -w -e debug false -e class com.sample.auto.androidBDD.MyAppCucumberAndroidJUnitRunner -e features /features/Release/ExecuteCommand_method.feature com.sample.auto.androidBDD.test/com.sample.auto.androidBDD.MyAppCucumberAndroidJUnitRunner

7. Dependencies ::
   androidTestImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-android:7.14.0'
   androidTestImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:7.14.1'

Comment: Can we get a [mcve] please?

Comment: @Robert , added sample in description.